# Barcode Scanner using Ionic/ngcordova, redirect to view

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router, ngcordova

I put a little thread on stack.  After scanning I need to redirect to another view find below my controller code.

I am unable to make this part work:

```
$state.go('resultscan',{id:barcodeData.text});
```

Code:

```
starter.controller('HomeCtrl',['$scope','$cordovaBarcodeScanner','$ionicPlatform',

function($scope,$cordovaBarcodeScanner,$ionicPlatform,$state) {

  $scope.scan = function(){

    //alert('nikoooo');
     $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {



        $cordovaBarcodeScanner.scan().then(function(barcodeData,$state) {

           //alert('accueil/'+JSON.stringify(barcodeData));
            $state.go('resultscan',{id:barcodeData.text});
           //barcodeData["text"]

        }, function(error) {
           alert(JSON.stringify(error));
        });
     });

  }
}]);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ionic Barcode scanner go to another view after barcode retrieved](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35038287/ionic-barcode-scanner-go-to-another-view-after-barcode-retrieved)

Comment: i remove the other post i am newon stack

Comment: What happens? Is there an error? Any console errors?

Comment: It does not redirect to other view and log says :

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'go' of undefined`

Answer (score 1):

The error is telling you that it doesn't know what `$state` is, or that it's undefined.  Try adding it to your controller:

```
starter.controller('HomeCtrl',['$scope','$cordovaBarcodeScanner','$ionicPlatform', '$state', function($scope,$cordovaBarcodeScanner,$ionicPlatform,$state) {
```

Comment: Being new to stackoverflow, you could upvote and accept my answer. :)